# Flex 4 standard practice for Custom Class creation and Skinning?

Tags: flex4, skinning

I have a basic app I'm creating with a Top Nav button Bar a bottom button Bar and a Viewstack for content in the middle. The catch is the content, and skins are completely dynamic based on XML I'm loading. Therefore I have to create the ViewStack dynamically (because I don't know how many children it could have) and the same goes for the top and bottom Nav button bars. Now, I could handle this very neatly with Flex 3 , however I want to to do this with Flex 4 and would like to take advantage of its new  logic and skinning separation architecture. I have seen many tutorials on this as far as components known at compile time but not for custom class creation. Can anyone list some good tutorials?  thx - Mike

Answer (score 0):

I could not find any tutorials , so I figured I would create my components dynamically as I would in Flex 3, the only difference would be that if I have a component I need to skin, in my case a button, and I'm creating it dynamically I would use :

```
btn_nav.setStyle("skinClass",skins.NavMainToggleButtonSkin);
```

Where the host component is : [HostComponent("spark.components.ToggleButton")]

I also am using  custom Spark Viewstack that a developer wrote:

[spark Viewstack](http://custardbelly.com/blog/2009/09/02/viewstack-in-flex-4/)

Also this article helped me with creating a custom component and connecting wih a skin class and how it relates to the component lifecycle:

http://flexguruin.wordpress.com/2010/12/08/flex-4-spark-component-life-cycle/

-Mike